# Get start time and end time of video

Tags: android, video

I want to capture the video through my application and also need extra information of captured video like Start time , end time , Quality of the video.

Currently I am using existing camera application to capture the video in my application , with sample code

```
static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

From above sample code , I am able to capture video and store on device but I am not getting any way to get that extra information?
Is it possible to get that extra info using existing camera application?
If yes then how else is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get that extra info using existing camera application?

No.

> If yes then how else is there any other way to do this?

You are welcome to use the time that you call `startActivityForResult()` as the start time, the time you are called with `onActivityResult()` as the end time, and [the quality that you request via `EXTRA__VIDEO_QUALITY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY) as the quality.

Or, write your own video recorder, using the camera APIs and `MediaRecorder`.